# WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc and minifyHTML not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My web using minifyHTML of WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc: [lovemama.vn](https://lovemama.vn/ga-chong-tham) Using WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc for minify HTML, but WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc Minify HTML not working in View Razor.
Am using new version: 2.12.0 and HTML not minify :(

- [Hinh 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ96c.jpg)
- [Hinh 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6RRF.jpg)
- [Hình 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwYrx.jpg)

`I want minify HTML View Razor with WebMarkupMin.AspNet4.Mvc`

Comment: Figure 3 is useless because the HTML code in the DOM and Style Inspector is always displayed formatted. In this case, you need to use the “View Page Source” context menu command.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur for two reasons:

1. Incorrect configuration of the WebMarkupMin.
2. Original HTML code contains syntax errors.

In the first case, I can only recommend that you carefully read the individual sections of the documentation: [ASP.NET Extensions](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/ASP.NET-Extensions), [ASP.NET 4.X Extensions.](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/ASP.NET-4.X-Extensions) and [ASP.NET 4.X MVC](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/ASP.NET-4.X-MVC).

In the second case, I recommend you to write [your own logger](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/Loggers) or use the built-in logger (`ThrowExceptionLogger` class). Logger needs to be registered in the `App_Start/WebMarkupMinConfig.cs` file as follows:

```
…
using WebMarkupMin.Core.Loggers;

…
    public class WebMarkupMinConfig
    {
        public static void Configure(WebMarkupMinConfiguration configuration)
        {
            …
            DefaultLogger.Current = new ThrowExceptionLogger();
            …
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am truy same you, but :(( Debug does not run here
[Debug not run here] -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlYdo.jpg

Comment: You have incomplete configuration of the WebMarkupMin. Reread carefully the above three sections of the documentation, and then make the correct configuration.

Comment: And remember that minification will not be performed in debug mode without the following setting:


`configuration.AllowMinificationInDebugMode = true;`